# Postgres: transfer only the current made DML changes from prod-DB into a older branched one

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, cdc

am a running a database of a accounting software. In order to fix some older transaction i branched off the productive one into a repair-DB, allowing me to perform some corrections in the past.
Since the prod-database still gets more transactions i would like to copy them into the repair base. This can be done via CDC or later, by mean of an extract of my prod-db beginning with a dealline.

So i do not want to have a complete sync, but a repair-DB that still gets recent changes form the productive db.

Any ideas are welcome!